# Configure Maven to use specific encoding for resource file in JUnit test

Tags: maven, encoding, resources

I have a problem with respect to the configuration (I suppose) of Maven and the encoding of a resource file.

There is a test I have written which uses large input data. For this reason I put a resource file to src/test/resources. While using Eclipse the test is running fine, but when I use maven, the test fails. From the messages it is quite clear, that the german "umlauts" (äüöß) are not converted correctly. I had the same problem in the test in Eclipse but was able to solve it by exporting it into UTF-8 from the database. But now I have this problem in Maven. So I reckon it uses the wrong encoding.

I have tried

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

in the properties and I have tried

```
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
```

in the configuration of the SureFire Plugin.

Both does not work the thing!

I can make it work when setting the InputStreamReader in code to use "UTF-8" but would like to know if there is a means of configure it the way that it works without that?

Comment: The `InputStreamReader` should always have a fixed encoding so that have the same behaviour in all environments. I don't understand why you want to avoid that.

Comment: Well, I agree! ;-) Apparently maybe it's a pedantic question. I wanted to find it out to see it working and see HOW it works. Next I would lean back and consider which of both approaches is better, that's where your argument comes well into the game.
But someone very well known (I suppose) has said some time, that, only because it doesn't make sense to do something is no sufficient reason not to do it! ;-DDDDD

Answer (score 0):

Update: This question changed between when I wrote this and now. You may wish to ignore it.

The source encoding of a project and the encoding of your `InputStreamReader` are not related.

What I mean by that is that defining `UTF-8` for Maven means that it will read source files and resource files that way *during a build*; however, it does not affect how your source code reads files into itself.

An analogy might be shipping some boxes across the ocean with a barcode. Maven handles loading the boxes onto the ship and pushing it off the docks, but your software is in control once you are on the open ocean! That means if you want your source code to open the boxes with respect to their barcodes, your software must also know about the barcodes. Maven doesn't dictate the downstream actions taken by your code.

Therefore, using an explicitly `UTF-8` stream reader is *exactly* what you should be doing. Changing your Maven configuration won't remove the need to have a stream reader with `UTF-8` specified.

Sources:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html

Comment: Well, I have considered already that it may just not be possible because Maven / Java would not apply any standard to the reading of resources. But then the question remains why it reads the resource correctly in Eclipse but with wrong encoding during the Maven build. So from my perspective the reason should be that Maven -> Java does something different than Eclipse -> Java, isn't it?

Comment: And I couldn't imagine that it is just not possible to control the way in which Maven interfers with Java - especially as the resource file itself is only handed over by Maven but not really processed. So it's only the transfer to the target directory where changes can be introduced? Or maybe the Surefire Plugin if that comes into game with providing resources?

Comment: I guess this depends on the DefaultCharset of the running JVM which itself depends on the System parameters for the JVM. I do not know further details.